# Save object to DB when email is received in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, mandrill

We are using the Django framework along with Mandrill. The app is hosted on Heroku. We need to create a new object in the DB whenever an email is sent to a specific address. I assume I need to write a script to fire every time a new email is received or to check the mail box every 5-10 minutes.

Anyone ever done anything like this? How can I setup a script like this? How can I do this in Heroku? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To fire a timely script use CRON.
django kronos is an easy option to use it. kronos has a good tutorial.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-kronos